# Showing only one root to a function by showing it is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show the function

$\phi(x) \ \colon= 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{2m-1} $

Only takes the value $0$ at $x=-1$ - I've already shown $\phi(-1) = 0$

I've differentiated $\phi(x)$ to get

$\phi'(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + ... + (2m-2)x^{2m-3} + (2m-1)x^{2m-2}$

If $x \geq 0$ then $\phi'(x) \geq 1$ so the function $\phi(x)$ is increasing for $x\geq 0$

If $x<-1$ then $\phi'(x) > 1$ as each pair $(2x+3x^2), ... , [(2m-1)x^{2m-3} + (2m-1)x^{2m-2}]$ is greater than $0$ so the function $\phi(x)$ is increasing for $x < -1$

Now the problem is showing if $x \in (-1,0)$ we also have $\phi'(x) > 0$ and hence I can conclude the function $\phi(x)$ is increasing for all $x$ and therefore $x=-1$ is the only root but I can't see how to prove the derivative is greater than $0$ for $x \in (-1,0)$

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\phi$ as a geometric series and differentiating from there?

Comment: Alternatively, you can take the derivative and see the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to observe that $x^{2m}-1$ has only one real root (which is $x=1$, since all the complex roots are $e^{k\pi/m}$ with $k=0\ldots 2m-1$). This would do, in fact $x^{2m}-1 = (x-1)\phi(x)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi(x)=\frac{x^{2m}-1}{x-1}$$

So, $$\phi'(x)=\frac{(x-1)(2mx^{2m-1})-(x^{2m}-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{2m(1-x)(-x)^{2m-1}+(1-x^{2m})}{(x-1)^2}>0$$ as $(1-x)>0,-x>0\implies (-x)^{2m-1}>0$ and $x^{2m}<1$ as $-1<x<0$ and $m\ge0$

Comment: @DonAntonio, have you observed the latest edition?

Comment: Yup, it came up *after* my first comment.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Noble, my pleasure. Hope I could make the idea clear